# NTP server return always same - wrong date (windows)

Tags: c++, sockets, time, udp, ntp

I want to get time from NTP server. I found lot of examples, but in my case I get from server always same date. I don't know what is wrong. I want get currect date and hour, but I don't.

```
unsigned char buf[1024];
...
tmit=ntohl((time_t)buf[4]); // get transmit time
//tmit=ntohl((time_t)buf[10]); //try this too
time_t tempa = tmit;
printf("Recieve time: %s",ctime(&tempa));
...
```

Here is my output:

```
Recieve time: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 1970
```

I don't know why recieve this date or why recalculate to wrong date. Where is problem? I working in c++ on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tmit=ntohl((time_t)buf[4]); // get transmit time
```

You are casting a single character (`buf[4]`) to a `time_t`. Since an `unsigned char` can only have 256 possible values, a cast to a `time_t` can only have 256 possible values. That can't be right.

Comment: If I don't casting is the same

Comment: Of course not. The problem is that there are only 256 possible inputs to the cast, thus there are only 256 possible outputs. The exact same logic would apply if you replaced the "cast" with any other deterministic operation. "There are only 256 possible inputs to the X, thus there are only 256 possible outputs ... that can't be right." Is true and points out your problem whether "X" is a cast or anything else. Every function whose outputs are purely a function of their inputs cannot have more possible outputs than possible inputs.

Comment: I change `unsigned char buf[1024];` to `time_t` buf and work. Thank you.